# Using attribute "Tapped" in ViewCell doesn't work (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, tableview

I encounter problems whenever i try to fire events when a ViewCell in a Table is tapped. I noticed there is the attribute "Tapped" in Xamarin.Forms' `ViewCell` but in the emulator this only works randomly in like one out of ten times.

This is my XAML Code:

```
<TableSection Title="Settings" x:Name="settingsTableSection">
            <ViewCell Tapped="Handle_Tapped">
                 <StackLayout x:Name="weeklyDoseCell" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="13, 0">
                    <Label Text="Redox weekly Dose" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>  
                    <Label x:Name="weeklyDoseLabel" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="2.10" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Label> 
                </StackLayout> 
            </ViewCell> 
</TableSection>
```

This is my Handler:

```
async void Handle_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Hey", "Does this work?", "OK");
        }
```

Does anyone see the problem in my Code?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I just realized that it only gets triggered when i press at the bottom of the Cell (around 1/5 of the bottom end). Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you making the method async ? Plz try it without the async modifier

Comment: Maybe the StackLayout or one of the Labels is "stealing" the tap 9 out of 10 times?  It seems like it should bubble up to the ViewCell if nothing is handling the event, but you may want to try adding the event handler to the child controls also and then detecting which control was tapped in the handler just to see if it works...

Comment: @Greggz - it needs to be async if it's doing something asynchronous... I think that should be ok to leave it.

Comment: Yes i saw that many times to make displayalert async, i tried the same with a non async method (Debug.Writeline()) and it was the same. I guess @ElementalPete is right. Can i add the same handler to Labels too? Edit: i just realized that if i put the handler on the labels the animation of the tapped viewcell won‘t appear? I definitely want that to appear. Any solution for that?

Comment: @ElementalPete Just as a means for troubleshooting. To check if the problem is not coming from the Tapped event. I never worked with it though. Only with ItemTapped from Lists

Comment: I think pretty much every control in Xamarin has a Tapped event.  You can tie them all to the same handler.  For now, just leave the handler code as-is to see if it works.  If it does, you'll want to check the type of `sender` - if it's a label, then the ViewCell is sender.Parent.Parent, if it's StackLayout, the the ViewCell is sender.Parent (or there are more elegant solutions for walking up the ancestor tree looking for the first parent of a particular type... just do a search)

Comment: @Elias Johannes Instead of creating multiple handlers you could just add a GestureRecognizer to the StackLayout. It might be a good alternative aswell if you' re not bound by the Xaml and can add something in Code behind

Comment: i already tried to add a gesturerecognizer but i encountered the same problem. I could add the GestureRecognizer to every element but i‘m afraid again to loose the animation when the cell is tapped. @ElementalPete so basicaly i should try to find the cell via parent and then fire the tapped on the cell instead of the label to remain the animation? Well it‘s a complicated way to get a Eventhandler but it might me the only solution haha

Comment: On my side it got triggered every time when  i tapped on the ViewCell, do you make sure that you tap on the viewcell not the TableSection?

Comment: @ColeXia could you provide a code example? I‘m sure the tapped property is on the Cell and not the section. But regarding the usage, what‘s the difference between tapping the section and the cell? I‘m sure i try to tap on the cell directly, not anywhere else.

Comment: I just edited the question, i realized that it works but only for a small part of the cell. Any ideas?